# Create a domain GPO with cmd only

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, domain-controller, windows-command-prompt, sysadmin

I have a domain controller running Server 2003 and the goal is to create a GPO for the domain without using a GUI program (no gpedit, gpmsc, etc.). How can I achieve this goal by using cmd only? (powershell doesn't exist on the server either)

Comment: Hi, why the need? just use admntool on a win7/win10

Comment: Those are the conditions, I can connect to the DC remotely and no GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, using `New-GPO` command on powershell.

On a modern Windows 10 client with `rsat` tools installed and also adding Module: `grouppolicy` in powershell. You can execute commands to administer and modify a domain from a client, that's what `rsat` is for. You don't need to do this tasks from a server. Yet I can't tell if this modern powershell commands can administer a Windows server 2003 domain. If you were on newer version, it surely could be done. You could give it a try.

Have a look at this MS link, there are all the commands to manipulate GPOs from powershell.

[commands to manipulate GPOs from powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Does the windows 10 machine need to be in the domain as well?

Comment: Yes it should. Technically not absolutely necessary, you could start a powershell or cmd with a different user (`runas` command) than the one logged in, but to make things easier I suggest you to use a domain joined machine.